# Uncommitted local files lead to error when doing git pull, how to properly unstage them?

Tags: git

I checkout to develop branch where i store my clean version of code:

```
git checkout develop
```

Then i try to pull:

```
git pull origin develop
```

There, i got this message:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    Podfile
    Podfile.lock
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I don't want to commit these files changes, so what's the best way to deal with that? Does a reset HEAD for the files work, as below:

```
git reset HEAD MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj 
git reset HEAD Podfile 
git reset HEAD Podfile.lock
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
git stash
```

then do the pulling and

```
git stash pop
```

but first read corresponding man page ;-)